# Правильное указание function()

Tags: jquery

```
$(".news_wall").find(".news_img").function(){
    if ($(this).attr('src') == '') {$(this).remove();};
});
```

Знаю что неправильно, как лучше разместить function()?

Comment: вообще как-то так:

    $('.news_wall .news_img[src=""]').remove()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если элементов много то получается нужно по всем пройти

```
$(".news_wall").find(".news_img").each(function(){});
```

А вообще

```
$(".news_wall .news_img").each(function(){});
```

Comment: find не нуждается в цикле, он сам себе each

Comment: @HappyCougar find() это вообще-то поиск дочерних элементов.

Comment: Да уже прочитал

Comment: @lampa, `.children(selector)` — поиск дочерних, `.find(selector)` — поиск дочерних любой вложености.

Метод `.find` вернёт массив обьектов (`nodeList`), что значит "сам себе `each`" — так и не понял. Подробнее, @HappyCougar

Comment: В общем то когда срабатывает find он возвращает nodelist вот потому надо использовать each вариантов других не видел.

Comment: @Crasher ну так я про вложенность ничего не говорил.